# Setting image width dynamically only works from variable

Tags: javascript

I am trying to display images in the browser. I want them to display proportional to each other, so I am scaling them down by the size of the actual image. They have all been scanned at the same resolution, so it will make their sizes proportional. Here is the function to set their size:

```
let imageSize = (image)=>{
    let multiplier = screen.width > 1200 ? 0.35 : 0.15;
    let width = `${image.clientWidth * multiplier}px`;
    image.style.height = `${image.clientHeight * multiplier}px`;
    image.style.width = width;
}
```

This works. However, I have to create a variable for `width`. If I try to set the width the same way I am setting height, it doesn't work. For example:

```
let imageSize = (image)=>{
    let multiplier = screen.width > 1200 ? 0.35 : 0.15;
    image.style.height = `${image.clientHeight * multiplier}px`;
    image.style.width = `${image.clientWidth * multiplier}px`;
}
```

This does not work. The width of the image ends up being WAY too small and distorting the image. I checked and the same thing is happening in both Firefox and Chrome.

This only applies to the width. the height seems to work normally. What the hell is going on here? This doesn't make any sense to me. Can anybody shed any light on why this might be happening?

Example:

```
let imageSize = (image)=>{
    let multiplier = screen.width > 1200 ? 0.35 : 0.15;
    console.log(image.clientWidth * multiplier); // 475.65
    image.style.height = `${image.clientHeight * multiplier}px`;
    image.style.width = `${image.clientWidth * multiplier}px`;
    console.log(image.style.width); // "166.6px"
}
```

Comment: Use ```console.log (image.clientWidth)```, ```console.log (multiplier)```and ```console.log (image.clientWidth * multiplier)``` to verify each expression. Also: If you use the width Attribute of the image and not the style.width attribute you only have to set one of width or height to keep ratio.

Comment: I did console log everything. On the first example, expected results. On second example, `console.log(image.clientWidth * multiplier)` would give expected results (about 400px). But `console.log(image.style.width)` ended up as something like 150px.

Comment: Does this example work in your case? https://jsfiddle.net/qajowubc/